# XHR progress events arrive too quickly

Tags: ajax, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest

I'm doing direct upload to S3 using html form and ajax. It's working good, files get uploaded. My problem is that progress events arrive too quickly. Like all of them up to 99.9% are fired immediately at the start of the upload.

```
var fd = new FormData();

// put data from the form to FormData object 
$.each( $('#upload-form').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
        fd.append(field.name, field.value);
});

// add selected filename to the form data
var file = document.getElementById('path-to-file').files[0];
fd.append("file", file);

var xhr = getXmlHttpRequest(); // cross-browser implementation 

xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
    console.log(e.loaded + "/" + e.total);
});

xhr.open('POST', 'http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/', true); 
xhr.send(fd);
```

also tried this way

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = function(evt)
{
    if (evt.lengthComputable)
    {
        console.log(e.loaded + "/" + e.total);
    }
};
```

Browser log looks like this:

```
[22:54:47.245] POST http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/ 
[22:54:47.287] 359865/5680475
[22:54:47.330] 1408441/5680475
[22:54:47.408] 2751929/5680475
[22:54:47.449] 3964345/5680475
[22:54:47.509] 5668281/5680475
```

and then nothing for the time it actually takes to upload a 5M file.

If browser info is relevant, I have Firefox 20.0.1

Comment: What does it do in other browsers?

Comment: **IMHO**, that event fires when bytes are sent across the socket from the sending end (which can be quick mostly); and not when those bytes are actually received by the server. That is the reason why you are seeing it.

Comment: @monsur Same behaviour in Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m

Comment: I am having the same problem. Doesn't matter how big the file is it seems to go straight to 100%. Would be nice to see an answer to this.